# Not able to clear the content of a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to set a value to cell X58 as then wait for 10 seconds and delete the cell value.

Issue = only value is getting set..

Here is the part of my code

```
function a(){
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Course');
    spreadsheet.getRange('X58').setValue('Hooray! Event is added to your calendar');
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
    spreadsheet.getRange('X58').clearContent;
  }
}
```

Pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clearContent` should be `clearContent()`

And you have one too many brackets in your code

```
function a() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').setValue('Hooray! Event is added to your calendar');
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(10000);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').clearContent();
}
```

This works